# APDU write command resulting in 6A 81

Tags: android, apdu

I am creating an Android app that uses an [ACS ACR1255 reader/writer](https://www.acs.com.hk/download-manual/7665/USR-ACR1255U-J1-1.03.pdf) to read from / write to an NFC tag.

I can read from it fine using this APDU command (which reads 16 bytes, starting at block 04h):

```
String APDU_COMMAND_READ_16_BYTES =
        "FF" // Class: FFh
        + " B0" // Instruction: Read Binary Blocks
        + " 00" // P1: 00h
        + " 04" // P2: Block Number (the starting block)
        + " 10"; // Le: Number of bytes to read (10h = 16 bytes = 1 block)
```

However, I am not having much luck trying to write to the card. When I try this command:

```
String APDU_COMMAND_WRITE_16_BYTES =
        "FF" // Class: FFh
                + " D0" // Instruction: Write Binary Blocks
                + " 00" // P1: 00h
                + " 04" // P2: Block Number (the starting block)
                + " 10" // Lc: Length of data field (10h = 16 bytes = 1 block)
                + " 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08" // String of data units to be written
                + ""; // Le: Empty
```

...I get this response: `6A 81`.

According to table 12 on [this page](http://cardwerk.com/smart-card-standard-iso7816-4-section-5-basic-organizations/), the `6A` part means **"Wrong parameter(s) P1-P2 (further qualification in SW2, see table 18)"**. However, table 18 says the `81` parts means **"Function not supported"**.

So I'm not sure what's quite wrong. Could someone clarify for me what the problem is. What command do I need to successfully write to the tag?

NB - The tag in question is a [MIFARE Ultralight EV1 MFOUL21](https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/data-sheet/MF0ULX1.pdf). (And I can write to it fine using Android's `MifareUltralight` class.)

Comment: Note that actually you are not using an APDU to write to the card. You are using an APDU to control the reader, and tell him to send the D0/D6 instruction to the card. MIFARE Ultralight doesn't support APDUs, just low level commands.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've just found the solution in this [Standard Instructions table](http://www.scard.org/software/info.html). That table shows that as well as the WRITE BINARY (`D0`) instruction, there is also an UPDATE BINARY (`D6`) instruction.

My tag already had data on the block I was trying to write to, so I need to use UPDATE BINARY instead. So just changing my `D0` to `D6` has solved the problem.

**Update**

These resources may also help other newbies to APDU:

- [NFC Forum - Type 2 Tag Operation 
  Specification](http://apps4android.org/nfc-specifications/NFCForum-TS-Type-2-Tag_1.1.pdf)
- [ISO 7816-4 Section 6 - Basic Interindustry Commands](http://cardwerk.com/smart-card-standard-iso7816-4-section-6-basic-interindustry-commands/)
- [Complete list of APDU responses](https://www.eftlab.co.uk/index.php/site-map/knowledge-base/118-apdu-response-list)